# Get lowest price from vue js array

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, vue.js

I have this array which loops through all the trips for a listing.

```
 <span v-for="price in listing.trips">
       <div class="price">{{ price.cost }} </div>
</span>
```

Is it possible to apply a filter, just to take the lowest priced trip?

I tried:

```
 <span v-for="price in listing.trips">
                        <div class="price">{{ Math.min(price.cost) }} </div>
                    </span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can just just create computed property?

```
new Vue({
    ....
    computed: {
        cheapestTrip: function () {
            return this.listing.trips.sort(trip=>trip.price)[0];
        }
    }
});
```

And then use it like this:

```
<span>
   <div class="price">{{ cheapestTrip }} </div>
</span>
```

You can also omit `[0]` if you want to have array. In this case use your view snippet.